# Not able to get data from array into a react-native-table-component Table

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am a developing a React Native app.My requirement is to display data from API in the table format.I am using react-native-table-component.I am not able to traverse through an array to display data in the table.Below is my code:

StudentFeeTable.js :

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View ,FlatList,Text,ScrollView} from "react-native";
import { useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import * as feeActions from '../../store/actions/fee';
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Rows, Col } from 'react-native-table-component';

const StudentFeeTable =  props  => {
const tableHead = ['Sl No.','Fee Name','Due Date','Fee To Be Paid','Due Amount']
const tableData = props.data;
console.log(props.data);
return (
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>FEE PAID DETAILS</Text>
     <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
      <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
      {
        
            tableData.map((Fee_Id, i) => (
              <Row key={i} data={Fee_Id} style={styles.text}/>
            ))
          } />
    </Table> 
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
 );
 };
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
 head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff',width:550},
 text: { margin: 6 }
 });
 export default StudentFeeTable;
```

In the console I am getting the below JSON data:

```
Fee_Id {
"DueAmt": 0,
"Duedate": "10 Jan 2020",
"FeeName": "Tuition Fee Inst.No - 2",
"TobePaidAmt": 360,
},
Fee_Id {
"DueAmt": 0,
"Duedate": "10 Jun 2020",
"FeeName": "Examination Fee Inst.No - 3",
"TobePaidAmt": 15,
},
```

After running the code I am getting error as below:

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tableData.map')

Can you please help me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you get undefined in the console before this value is printed ?

Comment: Yes first I get undefined and when I reload again I am getting the JSON in console.Do you know why it is like this?

Comment: try to do this const tableData = props.data||[]; and set a default value